# In Service Workers, is it possible to get a more meaningful error than "TypeError: Failed to fetch"?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Here's a minimal code of a service worker:

```
    if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' || (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request).catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            })
        );
        return;
    }
```

When there's a network issue, the error variable basically just says:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

We print this to the user in the "offline page", but it really never helps understanding what the problem is.

Is it possible to get something more meaningful?
Even if we could catch the Google Chrome code, like `net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` or `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`, etc...

Comment: Sadly those internal codes are not exposed. You can detect if the user went offline by using `navigator.online`. Combined with https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-network-error/blob/main/index.js you could probably at least know if its something dodgy like `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. This difficulty is why many products guide the user in extracting HAR logs, which give full detail. See this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=support+user+to+extract+har and this one https://www.google.com/search?q=har+extract+helper+support. Many products going that road. But yeh, pretty manual.